# Use Fuzi to grab text from a particular tag using swift

Tags: html, swift, parsing

I currently have an html file that I need certain text from, and I installed Fuzi to help me parse the html.  The part of the html file I need to grab the text from looks like this:

```
<pre class="lyric-body" onclick="location.href='SOME_URL_HERE';">
THE TEXT THAT I NEED TO GET IS IN HERE
</pre>
```

And what I have set up to start parsing the HTML:

```
if let myString = String(data: data!, encoding: usedEncoding) {
  do {
        let doc = try HTMLDocument(string: HTML_FILE, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        for lyric in doc.xpath("//pre/@class") {
              print(lyric)
        }

   } catch let error {
       print(error)
   }
} else {
     print("failed to decode data")
}
```

This currently prints:

```
class="lyric-body"
```

I have tried reading the Fuzi documentation, but nothing that I seem to try returns anything similar to the text I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XPath is incorrect, you're extracting the `class` attribute. If you want to extract the text inside the `<pre>` tag you need to use `"//pre[@class='lyric-body']"` instead. If you want to get the text inside directly you can use `"//pre[@class='lyric-body']\text()"`

As Fuzi have support for CSS-selectors you can use too the following code to get the elements with the class `"lyric-body"`:

```
for link in doc.css(".lyric-body") {
   // print stringValue or anything you need      
}
```

I hope this help you